# Add a button under WooCommerce subscription table in My Account page

Tags: woocommerce, subscriptions

I'm using WooCommerce and I'm trying to add a button under subscription table that is present in MyAccount page.

I've tried with this code but is not working:

```
add_action('woocommerce_subscription_details_after_subscription_table', 'add_switch_button');

function add_switch_button() {       
  echo "something;             
}
```

Can you please help me?

Comment: Are you using outdated templates?

Comment: I'm using the view subscription template that is provided by the last version of WooCommerce Subscription plugin

Answer (score 0):

Just missed the closing quote in your code after "something

```
add_action('woocommerce_subscription_details_after_subscription_table', 'add_switch_button');

function add_switch_button() {       
    echo "something";             
}
```

Tested with the current version of WooCommerce and WooCommerce subscriptions.